# How might I achieve this custon number formatting in excel?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, number-formatting

For the sake of this example:

```
100 copper = 1 silver
100 silver = 1 gold
100 gold = 1 platinum
```

I have a number that represents number of copper and I'd like to format it such that, in excel, it displays as a number of platinum, gold, silver, and copper. For example, "123456789" would display as "123p 45g 67s 89c". As far as I can tell, formulas by themselves are *not* an option because I'd like to do some operations on multiple columns that require everything to be in their base-copper representation (e.g. - "Highlight *this* cell if its contents are 10% higher than *this other cell's* contents"). As far as I can tell, I can't do this if the contents of a cell are something like "2g 4s", so I want only to *display* the contents as such.

I suppose one option is to have formulas, where one formula converts the copper value to plat-gold-silver-copper, while the other formula does the inverse? Then, in order to conditionally highlight certain cells, I make use of the inverse?

Something that we might be able to take advantage of is that copper-value numbers can just be split by two-digits each. For example, in 375938457, we know 57 is copper, 84 is silver, 93 is gold, and 375 is platinum. If any of the values are 00, we just omit them.

Is... this something that's too complicated for excel? Feel free to post any supplemental information or explain things in-depth. I'm *very* new to working with excel. (I'd like to do the same with milliseconds-to-hours/days/months aswell, which isn't as straightforward I think).

Comment: "I'd like to do the same with milliseconds-to-hours/days/months aswell, which isn't as straightforward I think."... What exactly are you trying to do? This almost sounds like an X-Y problem.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: Are you asking how to do this in [tag:Excel], or in [tag:Google-Sheets]?  There are subtle differences between the two, and someone has just edited your question to remove one of those tags

Comment: @Chronocidal I'm personally doing it in Google Sheets—so far, I've been able to adapt excel-solutions to Google Sheets pretty easily. If someone isn't looking at the "Google Sheets" tag but looking at the excel tag, I'd appreciate their input, so I'm looking for both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#0"p "00"g "00"s "00"c"
```

Unfortunately, I have only been able to test this in Google Sheets, not in Excel

Essentially, this just takes the formatting `#0000000` (which will give you at least 7 digits), and shoves text strings for "p", "g", "s" in the middle, then shoves "c" on the end.

In Excel, but not Google Sheets, you can also have Value Conditions attached to conditional formatting, such as `[>=5]"Lots";[>=4]"Many";#0` which would show the numbers 1-5 as "1, 2, 3, Many, Lots"

```
[>=1000000]#0"p "00"g "00"s "00"c";[>=10000]#0"g "00"s "00"c";[>=100]#0"s "00"c";#0"c"
```

Unfortunately, you can't use the formatting to make the extra 0 disappear between Platinum and Gold, Gold and Silver, or Silver and Copper.

`123456789` will display as `123p 45g 67s 89c`, but `246480369` will display as `246p 48g 03s 69c` instead of `246p 48g 3s 69c`

In Excel you can apply this from the "Number Format" at the bottom when you Right Click on a Cell and Format it (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>).  In Google Sheets, go Format > Number > More Formats > Customer Number Format

Doing this with *seconds* to hours / days / months is easy:

```
m" months, "d" days, "H" hours, "M" minutes, and "s" seconds"
```

Doing it with Milliseconds is *not*.  Official Microsoft documentation about Number Formats can be found [here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/number-format-codes-5026bbd6-04bc-48cd-bf33-80f18b4eae68)

Comment: Perfect, sir. Thank you. :) I'm actually ok with displaying the extra 0 there, too.